# javascript - Get every div that doesn't contain a child specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div group inside some that I want to have a class for every div that doesn't have a specific element like h1
For Example :

```
      <div class="container">
  <div class="parents">

   <h1>AAAA</h1>

  <div class="content">
  <p>Hello</p>
  </div>

  </div>
  </div>
```

I want to check each div inside some of it and get all the class that does not contain h1 and the result is like

> class = 'content'

I'm trying my javascript code via parseFromString because the html code is taken out from string

```js
var My_HTML =  `
<div class="container">
      <div class="parents">
  
       <h1>AAAA</h1>
    
      <div class="content">
      <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
    
      </div>
      </div>
`;
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(My_HTML, "text/html");
var output = doc.querySelectorAll("div:not('div > h1')");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Get all `div` elements.
Step 2: Filter the collection, keeping those that do not have an `h1` descendant.
Step 3: For each matching element, map the element to its `className` property.
Step 4: There is no step 4.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('div')].filter(d => !d.querySelector('h1')).map(d => d.className)
```

```js
const My_HTML = `
<div class="container">
  <div class="parents">
     <h1>AAAA</h1>
     <div class="content">
       <p>Hello</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
`;
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(My_HTML, "text/html");
const everyDiv= [...doc.querySelectorAll('div')].filter(d => !d.querySelector('h1')).map(d => d.className);

console.log(everyDiv)
```

Comment: How do I use your own code on foreach? My Code       [...doc.querySelectorAll("div > div")]  
  .map(div => div.innerHTML)         
  .filter(txt =>  
    
 // filter

)
  .forEach(Mora =>{

Comment: I don't understand your question. **If it's something about my code that doesn't satisfy the requirements of your question, please elaborate. If not, ask a new question.**

Comment: I want to use your own code inside the foreach

Comment: Nothing Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".container *").each(function(i, el) {
    console.log("Check Elements", $(el).prop("nodeName"), $(el).attr("class"));
    if (!$(el).is("h1")) {
      console.log("Class: " + $(el).attr("class"));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="parents">
    <h1>AAAA</h1>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This itereates each of the elements within `.container`; only looking for a Class if it is not an `<h1>` element.

You could also use the `:not()` selector.

```
$(function() {
  $(".container *:not(h1)").each(function(i, el) {
    console.log("Check Elements", $(el).prop("nodeName"), $(el).attr("class"));
  });
});
```

This will select the child elements that are not H1.